# Can I call a java class method from inside a flash movie?

Tags: java, flash

Can I call a java class method from inside a flash movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can call javascript from flash ( http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html )
2. You can call Java applet code from Javascript ( http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/js_java.html )

I am not sure there's a direct method of doing this.